# swift textview and labels return empty text in UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift

**Current Situation:**

I have a UITableView with custom cells. In the cells are 1 label and 1 textview.
Scrolling is enabled for the UITableView.
Below the Table, I have a button to save the entries from the textview.

**My Problem is:**

I get only the value from the first row. 
From the other rows, I get always an empty text, but only if the user has scrolled.
I don't understand why and I hope you can help me.

**Here is my Code:**

```
@objc func save()
{
   for i in 0..<labels.count
   {
      let indexPath = IndexPath(item: i, serction: 0)
      let cell = self.SearchTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", 
                    for: indexPath) as! SearchCell

      print("Index: \(indexPath)")

      if(cell.EditField.text = ""
      {
        continue;
      }else{
        ...
      }
   }
}
```

**Debugger**

First Row: [FirstRow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKMFe.png)

Other Rows: [SecondRow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuVog.png)

Comment: `dequeueReusableCell` pulls a (kind of random) cell out of the cell pool. It’s **never** the cell you expect. Anyway you should get the data from the model, not from the view. You must not use `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRow`

Comment: The cell view of tableview is re-use. It means although you have 100 data, it only creates 5 cell.
I think you could read your data list is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells in a tableview are reused, so a cell at an index path that is not visible could have values from a completely different cell. If you want to get all the cells that are currently visible on the screen, you could use `tableView.visibleCells` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells) to get all the cell that are currently on screen and extract data from there.

Alternatively, you could choose to not implement cell reuse and make your table view static. You can do this in Interface Builder, or you could also choose to create all the cells up front and return your pre-made cells in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. Note that a setup like this is okay for small datasets, but has terrible performance for larger sets so be aware that this might not be the best way to do things. It really depends on your situation. This method of doing things would end up looking a bit like this:

```
var cells = [UITableViewCell]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  // do all kinds of stuff

  for field in fields { // or whatever else mechanism you use as your datasource
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    // configure your cell
    cells.append(cell)
  }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  return cells[indexPath.row]
}
```

The third and last way you might want to solve this is to add a delegate to your cells and set the view controller as the delegate. If the text changes, call the delegate with the cell's index path and the new text value. You can then store this text somewhere in the view controller and read it from there when you save rather than pulling it from the cell's textfield. Personally I would prefer this method.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for ur reply.
I decided me for the 3rd solution and it works great!

Comment: Awesome! That's the best way to go :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterate over the cells in the tableview, you could just get the data from the data source.

Whenever the text in the cell's text field changes you could update the data source and then use the information from there to perform your save.

You must be having some kind of data source anyway, otherwise what happens to the text when the cell scrolls off the screen and comes back on again? If you aren't storing the text somewhere then you've got nothing to populate the cell with in the table views `cellForRow(...` delegate method.